# JS Не присваивается значение переменной

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var bal = 0;
    fetch('url', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ userid: userid })
    })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => bal = data.bal);
console.log(bal);
```

Выводит 0 т.е значение не присваивается( почему? в `data.bal` данные есть мне нужно использовать эту переменную в react

Answer (score 0):

Метод `fetch` возвращает `Promise` который выполнится в будущем. В то время как `console.log(bal);` выполнится сейчас. Единственный вариант проверить `bal` - это в `then(...)`.

```
var bal = 0;
fetch('url', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        userid: userid
    })
})
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => bal = data.bal)
    .then(() => console.log(bal));
```

`setTimeout` тут не поможет, так как сервер может отвечать очень долго. Или вообще упасть с ошибкой.

Если метод `fetch` вызывается в `async` функции, то можно использовать ключевое слово `await` чтобы в рамках этой функции значение пришло "синхронно".

```
async function fetchBalData() {
    let bal = 0;
    try {
        bal = await fetch('url', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({ userid })
        }).then(res => res.json());
    } catch (err) {
         console.error(err);
    }
    console.log(bal);
}
```

Comment: А как мне использовать переменную bal в react?

Comment: Реакт - это просто библиотека. Все, что есть в Javascript, есть в React. Поэтому то, что я описал выше, полностью валидно