# NodeJS как мне выполнить сначала fetch и после получение ответа остальной код?

Tags: json, node.js, асинхронность

```
let news;
fetch('http://localhost:80/read', {
  method: 'post'
})
  .then((response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then((data) => {
    // console.log(data);
    news = data; //Здесь получаю данные
    console.log(news);
  });
```

Сейчас у меня все приложение ломается т.к news изначально пустой.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1130037/js-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b9  Вот тут ответ

Comment: @Евгений я успешно получаю данные, проблема в том что само мое приложение выполняется быстрее чем сам запрос fetch

Comment: Ну? я же скинул вам ответ

Comment: Скорее всего вам придется засунуть весь код, который связан с данными которые в `news` в функцию. Может быть можно как-то по другому

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
async function fetchData(url){
    let news;
    try{
        news = await fetch(`${url}`, {
          method: 'post'
        })
          .then(response => {return response.json()});
    } catch (err){
        console.error(err)
    }
    console.log(news)
    // какой-то код
}
fetchData('http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/ceNgEyGaNu?indent=2');
```